# "KeyError: 0" when trying to load a sequential model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have trained a Sequential model in Keras using Google Colab to work on the Google Doodle data set. I am doing some simple image classification over here.

The following function defines the architecture of my model:

```
def create_model(input_shape):
   model = keras.Sequential()  
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding = 'same', input_shape = input_shape, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 3)) 
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

   model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 3))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

   model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 3))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

   model.add(layers.Flatten())
   model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(layers.Dense(28, activation = 'softmax')) 

   return model
```

and the following piece of code creates, compiles, and fits it:

```
doodle_model = create_model((image_size, image_size, 1)) #image_size = 28
doodle_model.compile (optimizer = "Adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
doodle_model.fit (x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 4, batch_size = 256)
```

I was getting good results with this model and so I decided to save it to deploy it later on in a web app. I have used:

```
doodle_model.save("my_model.h5")
```

to save the model

However, when I tried to load the model again with a:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model ("my_model.h5")
```

to make sure if it is saved correctly, I get the following error...

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-6cde554a8add> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
      2 
----> 3 model = load_model ("my_model.h5")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    268             raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
    269         model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
--> 270         model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    271 
    272         # set weights

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
    345                         'Maybe you meant to use '
    346                         '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
--> 347     return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    348 
    349 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     53                                     module_objects=globs,
     54                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 55                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    142                 return cls.from_config(config['config'],
    143                                        custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 144                                                            list(custom_objects.items())))
    145             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    146                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/models.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1404     @classmethod
   1405     def from_config(cls, config, custom_objects=None):
-> 1406         if 'class_name' not in config[0] or config[0]['class_name'] == 'Merge':
   1407             return cls.legacy_from_config(config)
   1408 

KeyError: 0
```

As far as I know, KeyErrors are related to python dictionaries but I am not sure why I am encountering a KeyError over here. Any help on why I am getting this error and how can it be resolved would be greatly appreciated.

Every piece of code, after the line

```
----> 3 model = load_model ("my_model.h5")
```

of this error message is some internal code of Keras and is not written by me.

Comment: I have got same error. I opened the model file with h5py and checked its keys. There were only two keys viz. ['model_weights', 'optimizer_weights']. This probably means the architecture was not saved at all! Can you post your keys from h5 file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you may be trying to load a saved model using a version of Keras incompatible with the version you used for saving the model.

What versions are you using in each case? You can check using:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

It may be that the fix for you would be to upgrade you version of Keras.

Comment: for some reason, doing a...

>> model = keras.models.load_model ("my_model.h5")

instead of a...

>> from keras.models import load_model
>> model = load_model ("my_model.h5")

did the trick for me. Not really sure about what was the actual problem, but I'll get to it and post it here if I find out.

Comment: @SudeepamPandey I don't think that would make a change. There must be something else that you may not have noticed.

Comment: Version mismatch caused me this problem with TF2x. Specifically, saving model with TF 2.2.0, and loading it with TF 2.1.0. By upgrading to 2.2.0 in my local machine the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of keras version mismatch.Check the versions before proceeding. Build a virtual env with all compatible version. Try using keras 2.2.4

Answer (score 2):

**What Keras version are you using?** If it is 2.1.6 then try Keras 2.2.4 or newer and your problem will be gone. It happened to me.